# Is there any way to generate custom errors/warnings in LaTeX?

Tags: macros, errors, compiling, warnings, error-writing

I want something like `\ifmmode\else\GenerateWarning{The command \backslash uzuka is supported only in math mode.}\fi`, which is supposed to generate a warning "The command \uzuka is supported only in math mode.". Is there a command or a package with this capacibility?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For LaTeX, use the commands described in section 4.9 of [`clsguide.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/clsguide.pdf):

- `\PackageWarning` and `\PackageWarningNoLine` if you are writing a package
- `\ClassWarning` and `\ClassWarningNoLine` if you are writing a class
- The internal generic version for warnings is `\GenericWarning`

The `expl3` bundle has another interface for warnings and similar messages, see Part III, chapter 11 in [`source3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/source3.pdf).

Comment: I'd add that the `expl3` approach has been designed to allow suppression of messages in a selective fashion. Packages such as `silence` can do the same for LaTeX2e messages but as an 'add on'.

Comment: @doncherry Thanks, fixed. (It's called `l3kernel` now instead of `expl3`.)

Comment: What was Part XVII is now Part XVIII Messaging (I presume).

Comment: For error instead of warning, use `\PackageError`

Answer (score 22):

Just use the built-in `\errmessage` for errors, e.g. `\let\GenerateWarning=\errmessage`.

The kind of warnings Latex generates are just messages; `\let\GenerateWarning=\message` will not interrupt the compile.  Latex uses the commands `\@latex@warning` and `\@latex@warning@no@lines` to create these for its own warnings: you check the source you find in `latex.ltx`.

Comment: Yes, that will allow to generate errors. But what about warnings? Is it possible to generate them too?

Comment: Thanks to search using `\errmessage` keyword I've found in TeXBook how to output warning. Actually I've found, that my editor (TeXnicCenter 1.0) treats as warnings output lines like "LaTeX Warning: \uzuka used outside of math mode on input line 211", which can be generated using `\message{LaTeX Warning: \noexpand\uzuka used outside of math mode on input line \the\inputlineno}`. Thank you.

Comment: Relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115976/8666

Comment: Is it possible to generate an expanded message as well?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `\typeout{msg}`. The command will print msg on the terminal and in the log file.