# Expansion of commands in errmessage

Tags: errors, expansion

When I run

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pet{dog}
\errmessage{My \pet\ is {sick}}
\begin{document}
My \pet\ is {sick}.
\end{document}
```

the error message is:

> My dog\ is {sick}.

but the PDF output reads:

> My dog is sick.

What's going on here? Why is `\pet` expanded, but `\␣` isn't? Why are those braces printed in the error message? Shouldn't I have to write `\{` and `\}` to get braces?

Comment: Meta: `<code>\&nbsp;</code>` prints as `\ `. (I like `\␣`, too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to
[[clsguide.pdf, §4.9](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/clsguide.pdf)],
the correct way to enter a space in error messages is to write `\space` rather than `\␣`.

To understand what's going on here, one must bear in mind that `\errmessage` outputs to a *text console*, while most LaTeX commands output to the *pdf being produced*. Commands like `\␣` are already fully expanded; all that's left to do is to execute them. But executing this sort of command doesn't make sense in a text-only situation. Hence, only a few commands, like `\space`, are programmed to make sense inside `\errmessage`.

Answer (score 12):

The document `clsguide.pdf`, in section 4.9 mentions `\space`, which is not `\`  (that is backslash followed by a space).

```
\newcommand{\foo}{FOO}
   \PackageError{ethel}{%
      Your hovercraft is full of eels,\MessageBreak
      and \protect\foo\space is \foo
   }{%
      Oh dear! Something's gone wrong.\MessageBreak
      \space \space Try typing \space <return>
      \space to proceed, ignoring \protect\foo.
}
```

Don't confuse `\space` with `\` ; the former expands to a space, the second one is unexpandable; you find, in the LaTeX kernel,

```
\def\space{ }
```

Answer (score 5):

Not quite an answer to the question, but related enough to warrant writing it.  LaTeX3 provides ways to format nicely messages.  In particular, within the command `\iow_wrap:nnnN` (and hence within all messages), `\`  is defined to expand to a space (just like `\space`).  The list of available formatting commands is currently

- `\`  expands to a space
- `\{` expands to a `{`
- `\}` expands to a `}`
- `\#` expands to a `#`
- `\%` expands to a `%`
- `\~` expands to a `~`
- `\\` goes to the next line
- `\iow_indent:n` takes one argument and indents it by four spaces.

Example (well, I should probably have made `\rescale` do something rather than always throwing an error...).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3, xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnnn { mypkg } { percentage-too-high }
  { The~fuction~\token_to_str:N\rescale\ cannot~scale~more~than~1000\% ! }
  {
    You~asked~to~rescale~the~picture\\\\
    \iow_indent:n {#1} \\ \\
    by~#2\%,~but~this~is~impossible.
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\rescale}{mm}
  { \msg_error:nnnn { mypkg } { percentage-too-high } {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \rescale{foobar}{3250}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How could I print a backslash in a LaTeX3 error message?

Comment: `\c_backslash_str` or `\iow_char:N\\ ` (the second one is more general and can produce any char like `\iow_char:N\~`).  Both work anywhere, not just in messages.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think `\edef\temp{My \pet\space is sick}` gets expanded to?

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pet{dog}
\begin{document}
  \edef\temp{My \pet\ is {sick}}
  \meaning\temp
  \show\temp
\end{document}
```

> ```
> \temp=macro:->My dog\ is {sick}.
> ```