# check order of references to floats

Tags: floats, hyperref, numbering

I want to make sure that the references are in in the order of the appearance of floats. I.e. I do not want to change the order of the floats but I want to avoid the situation:

> ... shown in figure 2. ...displayed in figure 1.

How can I issue a warning if a figure or table is referenced for the first time that has a higher number than than the following? Of course one would need to veto the case

> ...displayed in figure 1. ... shown in figure 2. ...displayed in figure 1.

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: @Werner: Yes, I'm using hyperref.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd suggest to check the number of the figure you're referencing at every reference, see if it's the highest yet and if not, check if its been referenced before. Otherwise: throw an error.

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Figures}\label{sec}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=2cm]{}
\caption{first figure}
\label{first}
\end{figure}

\autoref{first}
\autoref{second}\autoref{sec}\autoref{first}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{}
\caption{second figure}
\label{second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This results in

[image: compilation of code]

If I read your question correctly, this should be ok but removing the *first* `\autoref{first}` should lead to an error.

To achieve this, note how [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) treats labels: For every label, a command `\r@<labelname>` is defined consisting of 5 bits of information, in this case (for the label `first`):

```
> \r@first=macro:
->{1}{1}{first figure}{figure.1}{}.
```

Important for us: the fourth group consists of `<counter name>.<counter value>`.
This can be extracted by defining, e.g.,

```
\def\parse#1#2#3#4#5{\@parse#4\@nil}
\def\@parse#1.#2\@nil{\def\current@type{#1}\def\current@number{#2}}
```

Now calling

```
\expandafter\parse\r@first
```

saves `figure` in `\current@type` and `1` in `\current@number`. Note, however, that `\r@<label>` is *not* defined in the first LaTeX run, as its defined by `\newlabel` which lives in the `aux` file. Therefore, any use of it should always be wrapped in a test to see if the command is defined!

Next, we introduce a counter to keep track of figures that have been cited:

```
\newcounter{highestyet}
\setcounter{highestyet}{0}
```

Every call of `\autoref` should check the current value against this value. Let's collect everything we want to do at every `\autoref` in some command with one argument for the name of the label we're referencing:

First we should check if `\r@#1` is defined. If yes, we use our `\parse` macro to extract the counter name and value, otherwise we set them to `0` to avoid errors:

```
  \ifcsname r@#1\endcsname%
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\parse%
         \csname r@#1\endcsname%
  \else\def\current@type{0}\def\current@number{0}\fi%
```

The [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package provides the test `\ifdefstring` that we can use to see if the counter name is `figure`. In that case, we can use `\ifnumgreater` to compare the current value to the highest seen yet. If `\current@number` is greater than `highestyet` we replace it. If it is smaller, we check if this figure has been cited already. The idea is to have a boolean for each figure number that is set to `true` once it's been referenced. For this we can use the `\providebool` command (again from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) which stops us from having to worry whether a boolean is (un)defined before checking its value. In case it's false, we give a warning. Otherwise, nothing happens:

```
  \ifdefstring{\current@type}{figure}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\current@number}{\value{highestyet}}
      {\setcounter{highestyet}{\current@number}}
      {\ifnumgreater{\value{highestyet}}{\current@number}
        {\expandafter\providebool{figure@\current@number @isrefd}%
         \expandafter\ifbool{figure@\current@number @isrefd}
            {}{Warning!}}{}}%
    \expandafter\providebool{figure@\current@number @isrefd}%
    \expandafter\booltrue{figure@\current@number @isrefd}%
  }{}%
```

Ok, that's it! If we call this macro `\stuff`, all we need to do is to append `\stuff` to `\autoref` (or the reference command of your choice ... note, however, that the structure of `hyperref`'s `\newlabel` command was explicitly used in the parsing macro, if you use any other labeling packages, you might want to check that they don't redefine that!).

However, patching `\autoref` directly is dificult. Taking a closer look (`\show` and `\xshowcmd` from [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) are your friend here ...), `\autoref` actually calls `\HyRef@autoref`, which is the command that actually works with the argument, the label name, that we are interested in (note that the label is stored in `#2`!):

```
> \autoref =macro:
->\leavevmode \@ifstar {\HyRef@autoref \@gobbletwo }{\HyRef@autoref \hyper@@link }.
> \HyRef@autoref=macro:
#1#2->\begingroup \Hy@safe@activestrue \expandafter \HyRef@autosetref \csname r@#2\endcsname {#2}{#1}\endgroup .
```

We can simply patch this, using `\xapptocmd` from the [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package:

```
\xapptocmd{\HyRef@autoref}{\stuff{#2}}{}{}
```

In fact, in this case the `\apptocmd` command from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) also does the trick, in case you're working on an older system with no `l3` (and hence no 
[`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch)) support.

The same holds for any other commands that you want to respect this behaviour: for example, when using the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package (which should be loaded *after* [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)!), one can check that all variants of `\cref` (e.g. `\Cref`) end up calling `\@cref`, which takes the command called and the name of the label as arguments and stores the latter again in `#2`. So, as above, one should add

```
\xapptocmd{\@cref}{\stuff{#2}}{}{}
```

to the file (the same remark as above applies to the `x`). As they use the same counters, the commands will also cooperate, i.e. a previous reference using `\autocite` will also be detected by a following `\cref`, etc.

Now, the full document

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\parse#1#2#3#4#5{\@parse#4\@nil}
\def\@parse#1.#2\@nil{\def\current@type{#1}\def\current@number{#2}}

\newcounter{highestyet}
\setcounter{highestyet}{0}

\def\stuff#1{%
  \ifcsname r@#1\endcsname%
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\parse%
         \csname r@#1\endcsname%
  \else\def\current@type{0}\def\current@number{0}\fi%
  \ifdefstring{\current@type}{figure}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\current@number}{\value{highestyet}}
      {\setcounter{highestyet}{\current@number}}
      {\ifnumgreater{\value{highestyet}}{\current@number}
        {\expandafter\providebool{figure@\current@number @isrefd}%
         \expandafter\ifbool{figure@\current@number @isrefd}
            {}{Warning!}}{}}%
    \expandafter\providebool{figure@\current@number @isrefd}%
    \expandafter\booltrue{figure@\current@number @isrefd}%
  }{}%
}

\xapptocmd{\HyRef@autoref}{\stuff{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Figures}\label{sec}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=2cm]{}
\caption{first figure}
\label{first}
\end{figure}

%\autoref{first}
\autoref{second}\autoref{sec}\autoref{first}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{}
\caption{second figure}
\label{second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

compiles to

[image: compilation of second document]

If you remove the comment in the line `%\autoref{first}`, the result is the same as above (i.e. the warning disappears).

In practice you may want to replace "Warning!" by something like

```
\GenericWarning{}{Warning! Figure \current@number\space referenced after
     figure \thehighestyet\space on page \thepage\space without being
     referenced before}%
```

to produce

```
Warning! Figure 1 referenced after figure 2 on page 1 without being referenced 
before on input line 45.
```

(see also [Expansion of commands in errmessage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115976/expansion-of-commands-in-errmessage))

As a final note: of course this approach works for more counters than `figure`. For example, to also include tables, one needs to distinguish the `highestyet` counters, i.e. call them something like `highestyet@figure` and `highestyet@table` and add an

```
\ifdefstring{\current@type}{table}
```

check into the `false` part of `\ifdefstring{\current@type}{figure}` in the macro `\stuff`. This should include the same code as above with the appropriate counters at the appropriate places.

Comment: Great! How to make it work with `cref` (and `Cref`) from `cleveref` for figures and tables?

Comment: @Somebody see edited post.

Comment: Hi, may I ask why `\autoref{second}\autoref{first}` throws a warning, but `\autoref{second}` alone does not? It seems the warning is thrown by `\autoref{first}` if 1. `first` is referenced for the first time, and 2. a higher one has been referenced before. But this means `\autoref{second}` does not throw a warning if `first` is forgotten and never referenced - is that correct? Is this intended?

Comment: Next question, can this be used with `\ref`?

Comment: @bers yes and yes ;-) Sometimes things are numbered and not referenced; to get this behaviour, just add a test checking if the difference of `current@number` and `highestyet` is more than `1`, i.e. if you skipped someone. To use it with `\ref` just adapt the `\parse` macro and the name of the command you stick `\stuff` to...

Answer (score 0):

This is just an updated version of Jonathans code, it contains a small bugfix for users of the `caption` package and is extended for tables.

This also serves as an example on how to use this feature with the `fancyref` package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}


\makeatletter
\def\parse#1#2#3#4#5{\@parse#4\@nil}

%%Begin fix for caption package: %%
\def\@parse#1.#2\@nil{
  \def\current@type{#1}
  \ifdefstring{\current@type}{figure}{\@@parse#2\@nil}
    {\ifdefstring{\current@type}{table}{\@@parse#2\@nil}}
    {}
  }
\def\@@parse#1.#2\@nil{\def\current@number{#2}}
%%End fix for caption package: %%
%If you ar not using \usepackage{caption} then simply use this line instead:
%\def\@parse#1.#2\@nil{\def\current@type{#1}\def\current@number{#2}}


\newcounter{highestfigureyet}
\setcounter{highestfigureyet}{0}

\newcounter{highesttableyet}
\setcounter{highesttableyet}{0}


\def\checkfloatreforder#1{%
  \ifcsname r@#1\endcsname%
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\parse%
         \csname r@#1\endcsname%      
  \else\def\current@type{0}\def\current@number{0}\fi%
  \ifdefstring{\current@type}{figure}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\current@number}{\value{highestfigureyet}}
      {\setcounter{highestfigureyet}{\current@number}}
      {\ifnumgreater{\value{highestfigureyet}}{\current@number}
        {\expandafter\providebool{figure@\current@number @isrefd}%
         \expandafter\ifbool{figure@\current@number @isrefd}
            {}{\GenericWarning{}{Warning! Figure \current@number\space referenced after
     figure \thehighestfigureyet\space on page \thepage\space without being referenced before}}}{}}%
    \expandafter\providebool{figure@\current@number @isrefd}%
    \expandafter\booltrue{figure@\current@number @isrefd}%
  }{%
    \ifdefstring{\current@type}{table}{%
      \ifnumgreater{\current@number}{\value{highesttableyet}}
        {\setcounter{highesttableyet}{\current@number}}
        {\ifnumgreater{\value{highesttableyet}}{\current@number}
          {\expandafter\providebool{table@\current@number @isrefd}%
           \expandafter\ifbool{table@\current@number @isrefd}
              {}{\GenericWarning{}{Warning! Table \current@number\space referenced after
     table \thehighesttableyet\space on page \thepage\space without being referenced before}}}{}}%
      \expandafter\providebool{table@\current@number @isrefd}%
      \expandafter\booltrue{table@\current@number @isrefd}%
      }{}  
  }%
}

\let\old@fref\fref
\renewcommand*{\fref}[1]{\old@fref{#1}
\checkfloatreforder{#1}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Figures}\label{sec:figures}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=2cm]{}
\caption{first figure}
\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\fref{fig:second} in \fref{sec:figures} and \fref{fig:first}


\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{}
\caption{second figure}
\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

\section{Tables}\label{sec:tables}

\begin{table}
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=2cm]{}
\caption{first table}
\label{tab:first}
\end{table}

\fref{tab:second} in \fref{sec:tables} and \fref{tab:first}


\begin{table}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4cm]{}
\caption{second table}
\label{tab:second}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Reason for all this is, that the `caption` package changes the string you have to parse from:

- `{1}{1}{first figure\relax }{figure.1}{}` changes to

  `{1}{1}{first figure\relax}{figure.caption.1}{}`

  this also applies to tables
- List item labels of sections remain unchanged:

  `{1}{1}{Figures}{section.1}{}` remains

  `{1}{1}{Figures}{section.1}{}`