# Give an error if I don't reference a label

Tags: errors, cross-referencing

I would like to have LaTeX compilation (I use pdflatex) give an error if there exists one label in my document that I do not reference. Is this possible? This is to ensure that I mention every table and figure for which I set a label. I would prefer to use the same `label` and `ref` commands as always, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the package [refcheck](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcheck). There already a question you might want to check out: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87610/making-refcheck-work-with-cleveref). It worked for me in LuaLaTeX.

I'll give a brief example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    % ...
    \caption{A nice picture of my dog}\label{fig:dog}
  \end{figure}
  % As seen in figure~\ref{fig:dog}
\end{document}
```

With the second last line commented out a call of your LaTeX compiler (in my case LuaLaTex) will produce output like this

```
...

Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `fig:dog' on input line 8.

...
```

The output contains a warning that tells you that a label was never referenced. If you remove the `%` infront of the second line, the label will be referenced and therefore the warning disappears.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you elaborate on your answer" At the moment it's more like a comment

Comment: How can I turn the warning into an error though?

Comment: Refcheck has a command `refcheckxrdoc` ([doc](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/refcheck/refdemo.pdf)) to manually invoke the check (I have never used it). If the check fails you could probably throw an error by yourself (I have not done this as well) but [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/is-there-any-way-to-generate-custom-errors-warnings-in-latex) is a question regarding this topic. I would write a bash script to extract such warnings from the log file.

Comment: @FabianKöhler Thanks, I posted a follow-up question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253773/turn-a-warning-unused-label-into-an-error

Comment: @FabianKöhler also, please use the `@`. I was not notified of your message. I had to check manually.