# Turn a warning ("Unused label") into an error

Tags: errors, cross-referencing

The following example, a follow-up of [Give an error if I don't reference a label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253642/give-an-error-if-i-dont-reference-a-label), generates a warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    % ...
    \caption{A nice picture of my dog}\label{fig:dog}
  \end{figure}
  % As seen in figure~\ref{fig:dog}
\end{document}
```

The warning is:

```
Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `fig:dog' on input line 8.
```

I would like to turn that warning (and only that warning, not others) into an error. I would prefer to do this inside LaTeX rather than through an external bash script parsing the log.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea: everytime you add a `\label{foo}`/`\ref{foo}` pair the first compilation would give an error (because two compilations are needed before `\ref` knows there's a suiting `\label`)

Comment: @clemens ah good to know! There is no way to only give an error on the second compilation?

Comment: I don't know (today is the first day I heard about the `refcheck` package). But warnings are not too bad IMHO: 1) one should pay attention to warnings anyway and 2) an unused label doesn't do any harm, really.

Comment: @clemens I agree in general. But some cases this would be very nice to have I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a strange thing to give an error on, it's normal to label anything that might conceivably be referenced, but anyway

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\makeatletter
\let\old@warning@rc@\@warning@rc@
\def\@warning@rc@#1{\x@warning@rc@#1\relax}

\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\rc@unlab{Unused label}}}

\def\x@warning@rc@#1 #2 #3\relax{%
\def\rc@tmp{#1 #2}%
\ifx\rc@tmp\rc@unlab
  \PackageError{refcheck}{#1 #2 #3}\@ehc
\else
 \old@warning@rc@{#1 #2 #3}%
\fi}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    % ...
    \caption{A nice picture of my dog}\label{fig:dog}
  \end{figure}
  % As seen in figure~\ref{fig:dog}
\end{document}
```

This checks that the start of the warning is `Unused label` and if so makes an error. The test macro holding the string `Unused label` is defined indirectly by writing the definition to the aux file so it is not defined the first time you add this to the document, so that you have a chance for cross references to stabilize on the second run. You get a warning the first time, as intended for refcheck.